# error con Xampp MySQL shutdown unexpectedly Anteriormente se abría sin problema

Tags: mysql, xampp

¡Hola! De la noche a la mañana, el servicio de mysql de mi Xampp no se inicia. **No uso Skype** ni similares. Apache sí se inicia perfectamente.

El **netstat** del propio Xammp me muestra como **old socket** la conexión de mysql en la ip **0.0.0.0** puerto **3306**. Nombre: **mysqld.exe**.

También he comprobado que esté libre con la cmd de windows. Y,efectivamente, no está en uso. También he probado a cambiar el puerto a 3307 tanto en la configuración del propio mysql (**my.ini**) como en la configuración del propio Xampp en  la sección de "Service and  Port Settings".

Y seguía igual. Y, por supuesto, he probado reiniciando el portátil tras haberlo cambiado. Pero no  hay novedad aparente.  Sigue dándome el mismo error.  Por eso lo  he  vuelto a dejar en el 3306.

Os dejo el mensaje completo del Xampp control panel

> 21:41:14  [main]  Initializing Control Panel 21:41:14  [main]     Windows
>   Version:  Home  64-bit 21:41:14  [main]   XAMPP Version: 7.1.32
>   21:41:14  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.4  [ Compiled: Jun 5th
>   2019 ] 21:41:14  [main]   You are not running with administrator
>   rights! This will work for 21:41:14  [main]   most application stuff
>   but whenever you do something with services 21:41:14  [main]  there
>   will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think  21:41:14 
>   [main]    about running this application with administrator rights!
>   21:41:14  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\" 21:41:14 
>   [main]    Checking for prerequisites 21:41:14  [main]     All prerequisites
>   found 21:41:14  [main]    Initializing Modules 21:41:14  [main]   The
>   FileZilla module is disabled 21:41:14  [main]     The Mercury module is
>   disabled 21:41:14  [main]     The Tomcat module is disabled 21:41:14 
>   [main]    Enabling autostart for module "Apache" 21:41:14  [main]
>     Enabling autostart for module "MySQL" 21:41:14  [main]  Starting
>   Check-Timer 21:41:14  [main]  Control Panel Ready 21:41:14  [Apache]
>     Autostart active: starting... 21:41:14  [Apache]    Attempting to start
>   Apache app... 21:41:14  [mysql]   Autostart active: starting...
>   21:41:14  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app... 21:41:15  [Apache]
>     Status change detected: running 21:41:15  [mysql]   Status change
>   detected: running 21:41:16  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
>   21:41:16  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 21:41:16 
>   [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>   21:41:16  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
>   another method. 21:41:16  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error
>   logs and check 21:41:16  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more
>   clues 21:41:16  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
>   21:41:16  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums 21:55:28  [mysql]
>     Attempting to start MySQL app... 21:55:29  [mysql]  Status change
>   detected: running 21:55:31  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
>   21:55:31  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 21:55:31 
>   [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>   21:55:31  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
>   another method. 21:55:31  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error
>   logs and check 21:55:31  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more
>   clues 21:55:31  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
>   21:55:31  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

Y el mensaje del log es:

> InnoDB: using atomic writes. 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 2020-04-25
>   21:41:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0
>   [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0
>   [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Using SSE2 crc32 instructions 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size
>   = 16M 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128
>   rollback segments are active. 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0
>   [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12
>   MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ... 2020-04-25
>   21:41:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is
>   now 12 MB. 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to
>   start 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log
>   sequence number 1926016; transaction id 2085 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0
>   [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from
>   C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0 [Note] Plugin
>   'FEEDBACK' is disabled. 2020-04-25 21:41:15 0 [Note] Server socket
>   created on IP: '::'.

Lo más chocante es que en todas las veces en el log me pone **created on IP: '::'** aunque sí me haya funcionado.

Uso **Windows 10 Home**.

¿En caso de que no quede otra que desinstalar... ¿la base de datos seguiría intacta al volver a instalar 
 o habría problema?

¡Espero que podáis ayudarme! ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Revisa en el Event Viewer de windows los errores de aplicacion y los compartes

Comment: Uno de los errores dice: Error 25/04/2020 19:48:18 MariaDB 100 Ninguno y en  la  descripción General  pone: mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
En Usuario pone No disponible. El  que le  sigue  es una  advertencia en vez  de error.  Dice: Recovering table: '.\mysql\db'
A continuación  otro error:  Couldn't repair table: mysql.db.  Siguiente  error: mysql.db: 176 for record at pos 0.  Siguiente: Aborting.  Siguiente: Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Index for table 'db' is corrupt; try to repair it. Todos ellos de MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo errores registrados tienes una o varias tablas corruptas en tu base de datos, te propongo realizar el siguiente procedimiento:

1. Ejecutar mysql en modo recovery. Para lograr esto debes modificar el
   archivo my.ini y agregar la propiedad `innodb_force_recovery`
   Luego de modificar el archivo puedes iniciar Mysql desde la consola. Este cambio permite que el servidor se ejecute incluso si detecta una página corrupta.. [Info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

   ```
   innodb_force_recovery = 1
   ```
2. Ejecutar mysqlcheck en tu base de datos para determinar las tablas
   corruptas.Esto te ayudara a identificar las tablas corruptas.Ayuda sobre esta instruccion [Info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html)

   ```
   mysqlcheck -u user -p --analyze --all-databases
   ```
3. Exportar las tablas corruptas con mysqldump. Ayuda sobre esta instruccion [Info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)

   ```
    mysqldump -u user -p  mydb t1 > mydb_tables.sql
   ```
4. Eliminar las tablas corruptas. Ayuda sobre esta instruccion [Info](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-drop-table)

   ```
    DROP TABLE t1;
   ```
5. Detener el servicio de mysql y editar el archivo my.ini eliminando
   la propiedad que agregamos en el **punto 1**
6. Iniciar Mysql modo normal e importar las tablas exportadas en el
   **punto 3**. Ayuda sobre esta instruccion [Info](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-in-mysql-or-mariadb)

   ```
    mysql -u user -p mydb < mydb_tables.sql
   ```

Espero haber sido lo mas explicito posible, segun tu entorno los pasos o las propiedades de las instrucciones pueden variar para resolver tu problema por esa razon agregue un enlace en cada paso para que puedas ayudarte.

Comment: He probado desde el shell de Xampp. Escribo mysql y me responde: `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`. Pruebo poniéndo  en su lugar  mysqld y el mensaje es:  `2020-04-26 15:12:56 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2020-04-26 15:12:56 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.6-MariaDB) starting as process 17936 ...` Y al poner la siguiente línea me responde esto: `mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when trying to connect`.

Comment: (Me refiero una vez modificado el my.ini). También he probado a hacerlo poniendo la ruta de la carpeta bin desde  cmd(con y sin permiso de  administración). Al poner mysql me da el mismo error que desde el shell de xammp. Al  escribir  mysqld me da este otro  error: `2020-04-26 15:21:49 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.6-MariaDB) starting as process 5700 ...
2020-04-26 15:21:49 0 [Warning] Can't create test file c:\xampp73\mysql\data\LAPTOP-RA30SDBC.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to 'c:\xampp73\mysql\data\' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
2020-04-26 15:21:49 0 [ERROR] Aborting`.

Comment: Acabo de  darme  cuenta de que el error dice  que intenta crear  un  archivo test  en una carpeta  inexistente: `c:\xampp73\mysql\data\`... ¿Sabes dónde  está configurada esa  ruta, para cambiarla por  la  buena, quitando el 73?

Comment: En  ambos casos he probado  tanto  escribiendo user tal  cuál  como  sustituyéndolo por root que es  el que viene  por  defecto. Con el mismo resultado.